# What's the best way to dynamically change screen content based on condition in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have content stored in a database in certain patterns:

- [Image, title, body]
- [body, title]
- [Image, body]
- etc.

I need to display this information on the screen in that specific order. The user taps on the right or left side of the screen to navigate to the next content page. This is similar to an Instagram story but text can come in different orders.

Storyboards don't seem super flexible to varying content orders/type. What's the best way to identify the pattern as a certain template form then switch to that? Should the new template be a .xib, storyboard, or coded in?

I've noticed that apps like Medium or blogging sites can place an image or text in any order based on what's written. How is this possible?

Comment: How about using Tab Bar? Or swipe left or right to get to the new screen?

Comment: Can try stack view, and entering the view in a specific order. Will handle constraints & that headache.

Comment: "What's the best way"  What makes one way the best of all?

Comment: I apologize if I'm unclear- 
I essentially need a view that can adapt well to different content structures. In a similar way that blogging apps can accept images, text, or video for display depending on what was published. Currently using storyboards that define exactly where an image/text should go which does not allow for flexible formats. 

(I can use swipe to navigate between subsection but opted for tap. Their end functionality is the same to me (let's the user go to the next module page). There's already a tab bar to navigate between main pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the UIPageViewController in these cases.

UIPageViewController is a container view controller that manages navigation between pages of content, where `a child view controller` manages each page.

You can create multiple views that you want to construct and show them in child views.

I'll show you the example code.

```swift
pageController = UIPageViewController.init(transitionStyle: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle.scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation.horizontal, options: nil)
        
        pageController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        pageController.delegate = self
        pageController.dataSource = self
        
        for svScroll in pageController.view.subviews as! [UIScrollView] {
            svScroll.delegate = self
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            
            self.pageController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.viewLine.frame.maxY + self.view.safeAreaInsets.top, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height-(self.viewLine.frame.maxY + self.view.safeAreaInsets.top))
        }
        
        tab1VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MySaveListVC") as? MySaveListVC
        tab2VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyReviewListVC") as? MyReviewListVC
        
        
        arrVC = [tab1VC, tab2VC]
        
        pageController.setViewControllers([tab1VC], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        
        self.addChild(pageController)
        self.view.addSubview(pageController.view)
        pageController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

where tab1 and tab2 are child views.

You can move the view using buttons or swipe gestures.